# Perl reference Dereferencing for @var1 = [($a, $b)]

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, dereference

I have below expression in perl

```
@var1 = [($a, $b)]
```

Can anyone help me to deference the value stored in var1.

Comment: Why did you assign an array reference to an array in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@var1 is an array of an array. So its only content is another array containing two values, $a and $b.

```perl
$a2 = $var1[0][0];
$b2 = $var1[0][1];
```

Answer (score 4):

`@var1` is an array containing a single element. That single element (`$var[0]`) contains a reference to another array. That referenced array has two elements, containing the values of the variables `$a` and `$b`.

So `$var[0]` contains an array reference. To get from an array reference to the elements of the referenced array, we use the look-up arrow, `->`.

```
print $var[0]->[0]; # The first element in the referenced array
print $var[0]->[1]; # The second element in the referenced array
```

There's one extra syntactic nicety that we can use here. When we have two sets of look-up brackets separated by only a look-up arrow, we can omit that arrow. So the expressions become.

```
print $var[0][0];
print $var[0][1];
```

Two points about your code:

- `$a` and `$b` are special variables that are used in sorting subroutines. It is a bad idea to use them anywhere else.
- In your original assignment expression (`@var1 = [($a, $b)]`) the parentheses are unnecessary. Just `@var1 = [$a, $b]` would have done the same thing.

Comment: I started my answer with basically the same first sentence... :)

Comment: I'd love to know why this answer has received a couple of downvotes.